# in laravel how filter the data like search data?

Tags: laravel, search, filter

Im new to laravel im doing a project of questionbank how i multiple filter search for the table  with drop down select box?
like filter by the product price and product spec and product company and search the data
Please Help me
Thanks in advance

[image]

this Viewing table

```
<div class="container">
    <div align="right">

     <form  method="post" action="{{ url('topic/auto-search') }}">
        <div class="" align="left">
            <select class="col-md-3" id='sel_topic' name='sel_topic'>
       <option value='0'>-- Select Topic --</option>
       @foreach($topics as $topic)
         <option value='{{ $topic->id }}'>{{ $topic->topic_name }}</option>
       @endforeach
   </select><span>
       <select class=" col-md-3" id='sel_stand' name='sel_stand'>
       <option value='0'>-- Select Standard --</option>
       @foreach($topics as $topic)
         <option value='{{ $topic->id }}'>{{ $topic->standard_name }}</option>
       @endforeach
   </select>
     <select class="col-md-3" id='sel_sub' name='sel_sub'>
       <option value='0'>-- Select Subject --</option>
       @foreach($topics as $topic)
         <option value='{{ $topic->id }}'>{{ $topic->subject_name }}</option>
       @endforeach
   </select>
    </span>
        {{csrf_field()}}

             <input type="text"  name="search"  id="search">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" name="searchbutton"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;


    <a class="btn btn-small btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-top: 5px;" href="{{ URL::to('topic/create') }}"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;ADD</a>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<div class="">
    <br><br>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Topic Name</td>
            <td>Standard</td>
            <td>Subject</td>
            <td>Actions</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
```

And my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\TopicRequest;
use App\Topic;
use App\Standard;
use App\Subject;
use DB;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class TopicController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
         $topics = Topic::leftJoin('standards','topics.standard_id', '=', 'standards.id')->
                  leftJoin('subjects','topics.subject_id', '=', 'subjects.id')
        ->select('topics.*' ,'standards.standard_name','subjects.subject_name')
        ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')
        ->paginate(10);
        return view('topic.index', compact('topics'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $standards = Standard::select('id','standard_name')->paginate(10);
        $subjects = Subject::select('id','subject_name')->paginate(10);
        return view('topic.create', compact('standards','subjects'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name'    =>  'required',
            'standard_id' => 'required',
            'subject_id' => 'required',
        ]);
        $topic = new Topic([
            'topic_name'    =>  $request->get('name'),
            'standard_id'    =>  $request->get('standard_id'),
            'subject_id'    =>  $request->get('subject_id'),
        ]);
        $topic->save();
        return redirect()->route('topic.index')->with('success', 'Data Added');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $topic = Topic::find($id);
        $standards = Standard::select('id','standard_name')->paginate(10);
        $subjects = Subject::select('id','subject_name')->paginate(10);
        return view('topic.edit', compact('topic', 'id','standards','subjects'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $topic = Topic::find($id);
        $topic->topic_name = $request->get('name');
        $topic->standard_id = $request->get('standard_id');
        $topic->subject_id = $request->get('subject_id');
        $topic->save();
        return redirect()->route('topic.index')->with('success', 'Data Updated');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $topic = Topic::find($id);
        $topic->delete();
        return redirect()->route('topic.index')->with('success', 'Data Deleted');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index() 
{

  $params = $this->getAllParams();
  $topic = Topic::leftJoin('standards','topics.standard_id', '=', 'standards.id')
               ->leftJoin('subjects','topics.subject_id', '=', 'subjects.id')
               ->select('topics.*' ,'standards.standard_name','subjects.subject_name')
               ->orderBy('id', 'ASC');
  if (!empty($params['search']) || !is_null($params['search'])) {
    $topic->where("standards.standard_name", "like", "%".$params['search']."%");
  }
  .....

  $topics = $topic->paginate(10);

  return view("topic.index", compact("topics"));

}

public function getAllParams()
{
  $params['sel_topic'] = request()->get("sel_topic") ?: '';
  $params['sel_stand'] = request()->get('sel_stand') ?: '';
  $params['sel_sub'] = request()->get('sel-sub') ?: '';
  $params['search'] = request()->get('search') ?: '';

  return $params;
}
```

Your view

```
<div class="container">
    <div align="right">

     <form  method="get" action="{{ url('topic/auto-search') }}">
        <div class="" align="left">
            <select class="col-md-3" id='sel_topic' name='sel_topic'>
       <option value='0'>-- Select Topic --</option>
       @foreach($topics as $topic)
         <option value='{{ $topic->id }}'>{{ $topic->topic_name }}</option>
       @endforeach
   </select><span>
       <select class=" col-md-3" id='sel_stand' name='sel_stand'>
       <option value='0'>-- Select Standard --</option>
       @foreach($topics as $topic)
         <option value='{{ $topic->id }}'>{{ $topic->standard_name }}</option>
       @endforeach
   </select>
     <select class="col-md-3" id='sel_sub' name='sel_sub'>
       <option value='0'>-- Select Subject --</option>
       @foreach($topics as $topic)
         <option value='{{ $topic->id }}'>{{ $topic->subject_name }}</option>
       @endforeach
   </select>
    </span>


             <input type="text"  name="search"  id="search">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" name="searchbutton"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;


    <a class="btn btn-small btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-top: 5px;" href="{{ URL::to('topic/create') }}"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;ADD</a>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<div class="">
    <br><br>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Topic Name</td>
            <td>Standard</td>
            <td>Subject</td>
            <td>Actions</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
```

Comment: @mydeen Hope it help you out!

Comment: Thanks for your  help but its shows the error like **Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\reqeust()**

Comment: Yes Bro any another way. my problem is  multiple filter with search

Comment: @mydeen For multiple fiter you can use condition in your controller as I have answer in your controller.

Comment: Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\reqeust()

Comment: No check controller on function getAllParams(). in my answer again.